# Heading with text background

Tags: css, html

I want to make a heading, that looks like this

[image]

I tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<span class="header">Hallo</span><br /><span class="header">und Willkommen</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span.header {
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 43px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It works, but I want the line to break automatically within a `h1`, without using `<span>` and a `<br />`.

Comment: You're going to need either two block level elements or a single block level with a `<br>`.

Comment: I don't believe there is a pure CSS way to do this.  If this heading is going to stay the same all the time, and there are no variations, I suppose you could use javascript to count a number of characters, break the line and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two alternative solutions using mentioned restrictions

> "h1 heading without breaks and without span..."

**First one**: using only the heading tag h1 , 
**Second one** :helping with < a > tags

**First alternative:Using only the heading tag h1**

[image]

With small limitations you can take advantage of the **white-space** property with a value of **"pre-wrap"** (you can experiment with other values. I think this is the more suitable)
It will work as when using the **pre** tag.

Take care of starting the text immediatly following the first tag and in the same line. if not you will get an extra line in your heading
You break the heading as writing inside a pre tag.

```
<div>
   <h class="header">HALLO&nbsp;
 UND WILLKOMMEN</h>   
</div>
```

For the css you may avoid the display:inline declaration, if you will.

```
h.header{
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    /* display:inline;*/
    line-height: 43px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
  }
```

Little problem with the absence of right padding in the first line which I hacked with a **nbsp instance**;

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/63AWm/)

**Second alternative:Helping with < a > :**

[image]

```
<div>
   <h1 class="header">
       <a>HALLO</a>
       <a>UND WILLKOMMEN</a>
    </h1>   
</div>
```

Trying to keep your original .header class , I only modify the display to table and instead of padding for top and bottom i included a margin declaration

```
h1.header a{
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    display:table;
    line-height: 43px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin:5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/X5cfL/)

Comment: headers cannot contain block-level elements, like <p>

Comment: @Brian Stephens Correct!! Replaced with a phrasing content.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this set of attributes in a class to help me dealing with some problems of alignment (also cross-browsing problems):

```
.line_100{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%
}
```

if you want each phrase to use one full line and you don't want to use the `</br>`, you can add each line them in a  and call this css class I mentioned... take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UCxxg/) I made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clear: both to create line break without `<br/>`

```
h1.header {
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 43px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2m9n/1/

Comment: _It works, but I want the line to break automatically within a h1, without using <span> and a `<br />`_

Answer (score 0):

Without a `<br>` how are you indicating where the line should break? Or, since you are calling it "automatic", how should the code determine where to break? It might help to provide the HTML that you **want** to be using so we get a better picture.

If you use a single h1 with no other tags, it would have to break on width, I guess.